# Cloudbreak and Hortonworks HDP sandbox are same on azure?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, hortonworks-sandbox, cloudbreak

I am not able to find Hortonworks HDP Sandbox on Azure platform. and in search I am getting search results of only Cloudbreak. So they both work same or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same. The sandbox has largely been abandoned as a project, but it is for local VirtualBox development, not cloud VMs / servers. CloudBreak will create an actual, distributed cluster, which you will then need to manage yourself (this will require you to actually know Hadoop and debug any installation failure).

In Azure, you should be using HDInsight for being new to Hadoop, rather than trying to construct your own environment using tools like CloudBreak unless you are already working with Cloudera for managed services.

Or, if you just want to use Spark, you can use other offerings like Azure Databricks.